# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:******(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V--->JNI4net

Tags: java, eclipse, jni4net

I used jni4net and created a j4n.dll and a j4n.jar. eclipse understands the imports when I try to instantiate an object using a new button like `ISslTcpClient sslTcpClient = new SslTcpClient();` I get an error as follows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: firstdata.icvtnsclient.SslTcpClient.__ctorSslTcpClient0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V
    at firstdata.icvtnsclient.SslTcpClient.__ctorSslTcpClient0(Native Method)
    at firstdata.icvtnsclient.SslTcpClient.(SslTcpClient.java:25)
    at program.JNI4NETexample.main(JNI4NETexample.java:46)

Why am I getting this error? Thank you for your help in advance.

HERE ARE ADDITIONAL INFO:

I adds my J4n.jar in the build path and all the dll files plus the jar files in the root folder before the source.

AND HERE IS THE CODE: SslTcpClient  sslTcpClient=new SslTcpClient(); is the line that gives me dificulty.

```
    package program ;
import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String;

import system.Console;
import system.collections.IDictionary;
import system.collections.IEnumerator;
import system.io.TextWriter;
import firstdata.icvtnsclient.ISslTcpClient;
import firstdata.icvtnsclient.SslTcpClient;

/*import system.*;
import system.Object;
import system.io.TextWriter;
import system.collections.IDictionary;
import system.collections.IEnumerator; */
//This example is from the JNI4net example

public class JNI4NETexample implements  ISslTcpClient  {
    // {System.loadLibrary("ICVTnsClient.j4n");} //do not use .dll for loadlibrary


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException    {       

        // create bridge, with default setup
        // it will lookup jni4net.n.dll next to jni4net.j.jar 
         try {

                Bridge.setVerbose(true);
                Bridge.init();
               // Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new File("ICVTnsClient.dll"));
                Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new File("ICVTnsClient.j4n.dll"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         SslTcpClient  sslTcpClient=new SslTcpClient();      
        String csEncryptedString = sslTcpClient.Encrypt("C1 2005 151601 4111111111111111 0703 84.00");
        System.out.println("THIS IS THE ASNWER "+ "csEncryptedString"); 
    }

    public String Decrypt(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String Encrypt(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you load the `j4n.dll` library?

Comment: Yes. please see additional information above.